# Add Smooth Transition Animation on When Expand Grid Item

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

Can anyone help me how to add transition animation when reordering items inside grid. What I am trying to do here is that when I click an grid item, it expand and occupy whole row. Then other grid item will fill the gap left to maintain even alignment. I was able to do that but problem is adding the smooth transition. See my code below.

HTML

```
<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-item">Div 1</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Div 2</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Div 3</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Div 4</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Div 5</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Div 6</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Div 7</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
 .grid-container {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
        gap: 10px;
        padding: 10px;
        grid-auto-flow: dense; /* Fill empty spaces */
    }
    .grid-item {
        background-color: #ddd;
        padding: 20px;
        text-align: center;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: grid-column 0.3s ease; /* Smooth transition */
    }
    .grid-item.expanded {
        grid-column: 1 / -1;
        transition: grid-column 0.3s ease; /* Smooth transition */
    }
```

```
var gridItems = document.querySelectorAll('.grid-item');
    gridItems.forEach(function(item) {
        item.addEventListener('click', function() {
            toggleExpand(this);
        });
    });

    function toggleExpand(element) {
        gridItems.forEach(function(item) {
            if (item !== element) {
                item.classList.remove('expanded');
            }
        });
        element.classList.toggle('expanded');
    }
```

Comment: Exactly what are you transitioning? It's not clear to me what effect you are after. Please make a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tool like the [View Transition API](https://www.bram.us/2023/05/09/rearrange-animate-css-grid-layouts-with-the-view-transition-api/) to help you transition smoothly. Using CSS for this specific case isn't the answer. You should add the animation via JS.

The `transition` property is useful for transitioning between CSS states. Changing the postition of an item in the grid isn't technically changing its style, therefore, the property won't be transitioned smoothly.

You can check this by simply testing with transitioning other properties, like the background color in the following snippet:

```js
var gridItems = document.querySelectorAll('.grid-item');
    gridItems.forEach(function(item) {
        item.addEventListener('click', function() {
            toggleExpand(this);
        });
    });

    function toggleExpand(element) {
        gridItems.forEach(function(item) {
            if (item !== element) {
                item.classList.remove('expanded');
                item.style.background = 'rgb(221, 221, 221)';
            }
        });
        element.classList.toggle('expanded');
        element.style.background = 'red';
    }
```

```css
.grid-container {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
        gap: 10px;
        padding: 10px;
        grid-auto-flow: dense; /* Fill empty spaces */
    }
    .grid-item {
        background-color: #ddd;
        padding: 20px;
        text-align: center;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: all 2s ease; /* Smooth transition */
    }
    .grid-item.expanded {
        grid-column: 1 / -1;
        transition: all 2s ease; /* Smooth transition */
    }
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-item">Div 1</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Div 2</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Div 3</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Div 4</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Div 5</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Div 6</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Div 7</div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps!